# Is getting change through automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

If I set the main context's `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` to true and calls `save()` in background context, will the main context get the change synchronously or asynchronously?

My guess is that `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` is implemented by monitoring `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notification from its parent context or persistent store. If so, I think it should be synchronous. But I can't find confirmation in Apple's doc.

The reason I ask this is because I'd like to update the UI after calling `save()` in a background thread. So I need to make sure the changes have been propagated to the main context when `save()` finishes.

**Background**:

I'm thinking about performing all modifications to Core Data in a dedicated background context. So, if the user adds a new record in UI, the main thread will call `backgroundContext.performAndWait()`. The closure includes CRUB operations and a `save()` call. I set `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` in my main context, so it gets the change automatically.

The question is when is the proper time to update UI. I'm thinking to update UI immediately after `backgroundContext.performAndWait()`, so it's critical that when the `save()` call in background context finishes, the changes have been propagated to the main context synchronously. That's the reason for my question.

Maybe I should use child context instead? I think in my above architecture I use background context somehow like a child context. From the Apple doc, it seems that `save()` call in child context propagates changes to parent context synchronously.

**Note**: I know it sounds a bit ridiculous to use `performAndWait()` + background context. This is my first App and I originally considered using `perform()` + background context. I changed it to `performAndWait()` just because a synchronous UI is less confusing to the user. Also, I know I could just do CRUD operations in the main context (I will do this if I have to). I just want to explore the various possibilities of how to use Core Data.

Comment: Can you provide more context or code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @1337holiday I have updated my question. Please see above.

Comment: “so it's critical that when the save() call in background context finishes, the changes have been propagated to the main context synchronously” I think you need to stop thinking that way. You’re using the concept “synchronous” wrong in your head. Think how this works without Core Data, just using GCD alone. You get on a background thread, do something, and at the end you get on the main thread and update the UI. None of that is synchronous! Yet it works perfectly, and as responsively as possible. Synchronous is nearly always wrong. Don’t go there.

Comment: Hi @matt I think I completely understand what you said, but in my case I really think it's important to make sure the following two things happen in order: 1) the main context receives the Core Data change 2) the code updates UI. That's what I meant by "synchronous". What I'm looking for is a hook which is invoked after main context receives the change. I don't think there is such a hook. That's the reason why I want to figure out if the save() call in background context propagates change to main context synchronously. Let me know if I'm missing something. Thanks.

Comment: The GCD scenario is a bit different because it doesn't depend on main context receives the change made in background context.

Comment: @rayx What @matt said is correct. If you perform an operation in the background thread, its automatically async. Now seeing that you need to update the UI, your question really is how do you hook into the save to do that. Thats quite simple, just call your method to update the UI after you perform the `save()` making sure you execute it on the main thread. You will probably want to throw up a loading view while all this is happening btw.

Comment: Exactly. My whole point is that the existence of CoreData in the scenario is pretty much irrelevant. If you know how to do go from the main thread to a background thread to do something time-consuming and back to the main to update the UI, you know how to do this. The only complication is that CoreData itself is not thread-safe so you have to talk each context only on its one proper thread. But even that is not so different from the normal precautions you have to take not to talk to persistent objects on different threads.

Comment: Hi @1337holiday The function to update UI fetchs data from main context and updates UI based on fetched results. That's the reason why I need to make sure the change made in background context should be available in main context. If the change is propagated to main context asynchronously, call the UI update function immediately after save() may cause timing issue.

Comment: @matt Please see my replay to 1337holiday above (SO doesn't allow me to "@" more than one person at the same time).

Comment: Sure, I see the point now. If there's a problem with fetching on the main thread after saving on the background thread, it would help if we could see the code that elicits the problem.

Comment: @matt I work on the app by writing data model and underlying API first and then the GUI. I have just started to implement the GUI and haven't have a chance to do lots of experiments on that. My concern is that if there was really timing issue caused by that approach, it would be intermittent and hard to debug. So I'm thinking to change the approach to use child context instead. Apple doc doesn't say explicitly that save() in child context is synchronous, but it's almost certain it is.

Comment: @rayx In that situation you can make your background contexts a child of the main context and save both in a `perform` block. Best example i can find is something like this article https://medium.com/killingmeswiftly/core-data-part-2-child-contexts-and-multiple-managed-object-contexts-9e881519997f

Comment: @1337holiday Yes, that's what I thought. Thanks for the pointer.